# xm cloud webhooks with sendgrid integration

Tags: xm-cloud

I tried to intergrade "xm cloud webhooks with sendgrid".
Please find the sendgrid URL below:
https://app.sendgrid.com/
Although I have done all configuration related to this, when i applied the same for workflow. Mail has not been triggered.
Could any one of you please suggest.

Twilio SendGridTwilio SendGrid
SendGrid
Delivering your transactional and marketing email through one reliable platform.

Comment: It would be nice if you share more information on what you tried.

Comment: @pawan could you please add more details like the steps you followed for this and error you are getting

Comment: Thanks @Nikhil, What we have, we have send grid license as well as we are using sitecore xm cloud.
PLease find the below steps for managing the connection between Sitecore Webhooks and send grid
1)- create webhook event handlers under the /sitecore/system/Webhooks section in the content tree.
2)- then adding the Rule
3)- Enabled: for Enable or disable the event handler.
4)- Url
5)- Authorization:
6)- Serialization Type
Note:- Please follow below link:- 
https://medium.com/@prabhu.ranganathan/sitecore-webhooks-what-you-need-to-know-a2c3fac6a02c

Comment: @pawanTyagi I would suggest checking with Sitecore support. Also please check do you need anything to be configured in Sendgrid follow https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/tracking-events/getting-started-event-webhook

Comment: HI @pawanTyagi - did you try to add an authorization item to a webhook, please see this URL for the reference https://doc.sitecore.com/xmc/en/developers/xm-cloud/walkthrough--using-an-authorization-item.html